# Frame within a frame with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, pack

I am trying to create a frame within a frame with the following code but somehow instead of maintaining the frame's individual dimensions, it takes the last known width and height and draws both the frame of equal height and width. How can I get to have different widths and heights and maintain a frame within a frame?

```
root = tk.Tk()
f1 = Frame(root,width = 700, height = 520, colormap = "new",highlightbackground="black",  highlightthickness=3)
f2= Frame(f1, width = 200, height = 210, colormap = "new",highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=1)
f1.pack()
f2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want exactly.  What is wrong in your code currently?  What is the output you expect?

Comment: When you run the above code, both the frame f1 and f2 superimpose on each other and have the same length and width ( but in my coide, the lengths and widths are different for the frames). How do I get to have different heights and widths?